# How to display a UIPickerView when selecting row in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a UITableView with some rows in it. Is it possible to show a UIPickerView when tapping on a row in the table?

I want the UIPickerView to change its data depending on which row it the UITableView that is selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a delegate set for UITableView then that view will send you the appropriate delegate methods. From there you can reload your picker view. Click [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html) to find out more.

edited: corrected link.